# How to start recognizing tones and accents?

Tags: self-learning, accent-reduction, informal-learning

I would like to start recognizing tones, accents and stresses in languages I already know. Are there efficient ways to do this?

---

*For a little more background* : I have recently become aware of the phenomenon of pitch accents ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitch_accent_(intonation)#Pitch_accent_in_English) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_pitch_accent), although the articles are far too advanced for me) after starting to learn Mandarin tones.

Interestingly, Japanese (where I can follow and participate in simple conversations) seems to have a pitch accent. English and German, though mostly stress-based from what I can read, also appear to use pitch changes in some cases. I'm hoping to train my brain to recognize those accents in languages I know and use, in hopes to be able to learn them better, and eventually to improve my speech.

Comment: Interesting, the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tone_(linguistics)) lists a few different *types* of tones (I had no idea this was a thing, so this is really cool for me): register, contour, and the less-defined pitch-accent. Ok, let me get lost in the Internet for the next while...

Comment: Hehe, seems I lured another foolish adventurer into this maze of linguistics! :)

Comment: What do you mean by "languages you already know"? I would guess that for many languages with a tonal component learning it is a rather important initiation step... It isn't so much of an issue in Japanese as far as I know, but in Mandarin at least it's almost stereotypically vital?

Comment: I'm hoping that understanding the language will let me catch and get accustomed to pitch changes while casually listening to people speaking. If that's a thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since this question isn't a [reference-request](/questions/tagged/reference-request), I will answer from personal experience and *Internet*.

The closest to a tonal language that I have studied is Japanese, which only goes as far as pitch-accent (so it doesn't really count). However, throughout my involvement in my university's Asian language department and social experiences I've had contact with a few native English speakers learning Mandarin.

I asked one of my acquaintances who is learning Mandarin, who explained (parenthetical statements mine):

> Part of it (recognizing tones) is experience, but a lot is context, deciding what makes the most sense for ... the circumstance
>
> They (the tones) are reasonably distinct
>
> [P]racticing speaking it actually helps you hear them better too

---

One more piece of advice I can give is to *not* rely on songs for learning to recognize the tones. [As this answer on Chinese.SE pointed out](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/572):

> In songs, most tones disappear. The syllables are sung along the melody of music.

And I have heard similar in the Japanese learning community. This sentiment may not be applicable across the board, but it applies to at least two of the languages you mentioned.

Comment: The bit about songs is interesting, I initially thought about using lyrics. I will... try to apply your comment about context on some of what I hear. Will report back when I hear some changes :)